# How to avoid saving a value of property of form object when saving changes to db

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

In a crud asp.net core 2.2 web app, I need to avoid saving a property of form object to db. How do I do that?

I've tried using [Editable(false)] data annotation on the ListBin property to prevent saving property value to db.

```
[Table("supply_lists")]
public partial class SupplyLists
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("category_id")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("coursecode")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Coursecode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("title")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("filename")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [Column("isactive")]
    public bool Isactive { get; set; }
    [Column("date", TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column("list_bin")]
    public byte[] ListBin { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [InverseProperty("SupplyLists")]
    public virtual SupplyListCategory Category { get; set; }
}


[ModelMetadataType(typeof(MetaDataTypeModel))]
public partial class SupplyLists
{

}
public class MetaDataTypeModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    public byte[] ListBin { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Active")]
    public bool Isactive { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Course Code")]
    public string Coursecode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SupplyListCore22.Models.SupplyListsContext _context;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public EditModel(SupplyListCore22.Models.SupplyListsContext context, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _context = context;
        _env = env;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public SupplyLists SupplyLists { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public FileUpload FileUpload { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        SupplyLists = await _context.SupplyLists
            .Include(s => s.Category).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (SupplyLists == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
       ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.SupplyListCategory, "Id", "Category");
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
        //    return Page();
        //}

        _context.Attach(SupplyLists).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (FileUpload.UploadSupplyList != null)
        {
            var fileUploadData = await utilities.utilities.ProcessFormFile(FileUpload.UploadSupplyList, ModelState);
            if (ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
            {
                ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.SupplyListCategory, "Id", "Category");
                return Page();
            }
            var sl = _context.SupplyLists.Find(SupplyLists.Id);
            sl.ListBin = fileUploadData;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

It set the ListBin to null in db which is not what I wanted when saving changes (I wanted to preserve the old value of ListBin in db).

Comment: Using Razor Pages.

Comment: The easiest way would be get the old value and set it to the new object.

Comment: Why do you edit the ListBin property if you want to preserve the old value of ListBin in db ?

Comment: The crud pages are set up so the ListBin prop is set to a value on Create page.  On Edit page, there is option to set to a new value or preserve the old value.  If the choice was to preserve the value, the above code set it to null.  The model class was created from the existing sql db using scaffolding and I do not want to modify this class that could be lost if I recreate the class via scaffolding.